# UMVUE: either lower bound or variance has problem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, variance, parameter-estimation

For $f(x) = θ(1-θ)^x$; I get $E(x)=(1-θ)/θ$ and variance $= (1-θ)/nθ^2$. For lower bound I get $(θ^2)*(1-θ)/n$ which is not equal to the variance.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please define the meaning of the variables $f$, $x$, $\theta $ and so on.

Comment: x=0,1,2,...; 0<θ<1. f(x) is the pdf.

Comment: I find the lower bound by taking ln (log), then we take first and second derivative. the second derivative comes out to be  (-1/θ^2) - x/(1-θ)^2 . Then I take expectation and so replace the x with the expected value E(x). I get -1/(θ^2)(1-θ) . Then the last step is to multiply with -1 and 'n' and then take reciprocal of it. Which gives [(θ^2)(1-θ)]/n.
It is not equal to the variance, it should be equal to the variance I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess that you meant $g_n = \bar{X}_n$ as an estimator of $g(\theta) =  (1-\theta)/\theta$, where $X =0,1,2,...$   As such, for finding the Cramer-Rao lower bound you have to find Fisher's information 
$$
\ln f(x;\theta)= \ln \theta+x\ln(1-\theta),
$$ 
hence
$$
I_X (\theta) = - \mathbb{E} ( \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial\theta^2} \ln f(x;\theta))= \frac{1}{\theta^2} +\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}\mathbb{E}X= \frac{1}{\theta^2} +\frac{1}{(1-\theta)\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta^2 ( 1 - \theta)}. 
$$
Now recall that for $I_{X}(g(\theta))$ you should use 
$$
I_{X}(g(\theta)) = (g'(\theta)^{-2} I_X(\theta) = \theta^4\frac{1}{\theta^2 ( 1 - \theta)}  = \frac{\theta^2}{(1-\theta)}.
$$

Thus the CRLB for unbiased estimators of $g(\theta)$ is 
$$
\frac{1}{nI_X(g( \theta) )} = \frac{ ( 1 - \theta)}{\theta^2n}.
$$
And the variance of $\bar{X}_n$ is 
$$
Var(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{var(X)}{n} = \frac{(1-\theta)}{n \theta^2} = CRLB.
$$